# jq: how to filter for a key that is a numeric string stored in a variable?

Tags: json, bash, jq

Firstly, apologies if this has been asked before (though I don't think it has).

I have a json-string that I am receiving as the output of a cURL command in a bash-script.
It looks a little something like this:

```
{"123456": {"extract": "this is the bit I am looking for"}}
```

Now, the key "123456" is dynamic, and I actually need it to form the url for the cURL command. Because of this, the string "123456" is stored as a variable called $PAGE_ID.
How can I use jq to access the value corresponding to this key? I have tried many different iterations based on the jq documentation such as:

```
curl "$URL$PAGE_ID" | jq '.["$PAGE_ID"]'
curl "$URL$PAGE_ID" | jq '.[env.PAGE_ID]'
curl "$URL$PAGE_ID" | jq ".[$PAGE_ID]"
```

and they are all somehow-problematic (there is no string interpolation in the first one, the second one returns null and the third one technically looks for the numeric value 123456 in the dictionary and not the string-equivalent).

Is there any way to find the value corresponding to a key that is both a numeric string AND stored in a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully the following script answers the question.

```
#!/bin/bash

function data {
  cat <<EOF
{"123456": {"extract": "this is the bit I am looking for"}}
EOF
}

PAGE_ID=123456
data | jq -c --arg pid "$PAGE_ID" '.[$pid]'

data | jq --arg pid "$PAGE_ID" '.[$pid].extract'
```

#### Output

```
{"extract":"this is the bit I am looking for"}
"this is the bit I am looking for"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
$ jq --arg pageid "$PAGE_ID" 'to_entries[] | select(.key==$pageid) | .value' <<<'{"123456": {"extract": "this is the bit I am looking for"}}'
{
  "extract": "this is the bit I am looking for"
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use double quotes to force numeric value to be a key :

```
PAGE_ID=123456
jq ".\"$PAGE_ID\"" <<< '{"123456": {"extract": "this is the bit I am looking for"}}'
# {
#   "extract": "this is the bit I am looking for"
# }
```

Comment: True, but not for all releases of jq, and a bit brittle.

Comment: @peak It works from 1.4 which is 6 years old. For jq, 1.3 is like the prehistoric version. It could be a bit brittle, but it's in official documentation and there is no problem if PAGE_ID contains only numeric values.

Comment: All true, as I said.